# Can I create tabular data fields in a Dexterity?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm a newbie to Stack Overflow and I've just started developing an intranet site to document the results of a user study we're conducting.

I'm using Plone 4.1 and have just started learning to use the Dexterity framework as the pages to display the results of our findings follow a fixed structure. As per our requirements for the site, I've created the rich text and integer fields successfully. However, one of the requirements is for a 2-column tabular field with a variable number of rows. Is it possible to model this in Dexterity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [collective.z3cform.datagridfield](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.z3cform.datagridfield) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like what I need. Based on the example doc, I've managed to add a new field using collective.z3cform.datagridfield and assign this to a DictRow type in my schema code. I can now add and remove rows of the table in the Edit view but when I click Save the form displays an inline validation error: "The system could not process the given value". Do I need to add any additional code for handling saving data in the form?

Comment: The data grid field can be a bit finicky. Feel free to ask a new question here or on the plone-users mailing list and provide more details about the schema of the DictRow and what values you are trying to save.

Comment: Ok, will do. It sounds like datagridfield is the way to go. Obviously there's something about the datagrid documentation I haven't fully understood so I'll post a new question on datagrid here. Thanks for your help.